# How to get last completed 15 minutes using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Suppose current time is `16:44` then i should get the result as `16:30` .
Or say time 2:07 then i should get the result as 2:00.And my start time is 9:00 AM 
so if now time is 9:05 it should show 9:00 and if time is 9:16 should show 9:15.
Is there any solution ?

Summary:

**Input** : 16:44

**Output** : 16:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can do it using pure Javascript:

```js
var round = 1000 * 60 * 15;
var date = new Date(); //or use any other date
var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / round) * round)
console.log(moment(rounded).format("HH:mm"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
moment.utc(
  moment(
    time1, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(
      time2(then, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
  )
).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: there is no two time available .

Comment: Then you can use .add(15, 'Minutes') instead of the .diff